# How can I send multiple requests to the Game Coordinator?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with the node-globaloffensive library and want to send multiple requests to the gc to get every rank from every user in my database. With my current code it is repeating all over again and I'm only getting one request back. Do you have andy ideas how I can send and receive every profile?

My current code:

```
const SteamUser = require('steam-user');
const SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
const GlobalOffensive = require('globaloffensive');
const config = require('./config');
const db = require('./database');

var SteamID = require('steamid');
var mysql = require('mysql');

let user = new SteamUser();
let csgo = new GlobalOffensive(user);

csgo.on('debug', console.log);
user.on('error', console.error);

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  supportBigNumbers: true,
  bigNumberStrings: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: db.host,
  user: db.user,
  password: db.password,
  database: db.dbname
});

const logInOptions = {
  accountName: config.accountName,
  password: config.password
}

user.logOn(logInOptions);

user.on('loggedOn', res => {
  console.log("Logged into Steam as " + user.steamID.getSteam3RenderedID());

  user.setPersona(SteamUser.EPersonaState.Online);
  user.gamesPlayed(730);

});

csgo.on("connectedToGC", function() {
    console.log("connectedToGC");
    const checkData = setInterval(()=>{

    //Check connection to game coordinator
    if ( csgo.haveGCSession ) {

      //Check Database
      pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (MainSteamGroup = '1' || CommunitySteamGroup = '1' || vip = '1') && BotInFriendlist = '1'", function (err, rows, fields) {
          connection.release();
          if (err) throw err;
          rows.forEach( (row) => {
            var account_id = new SteamID(`${row.SteamID64}`);

            //Request Data from CS:GO
            csgo.requestPlayersProfile(account_id, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("before");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    //do what you need here
                }, 2000);
                console.log("after");
            });
          });
        });
      });
    };
  }, 10000);
});
```

Log:

```
Logged into Steam as [U:1:xxxxxxxxxx]
Sending GC message ClientHello
Sending hello, setting timer for next attempt to 2000 ms
Sending GC message ClientHello
Sending hello, setting timer for next attempt to 4000 ms
Got handled GC message ClientWelcome
Unknown SO type 2 with 1 items
Unknown SO type 7 with 1 items
GC connection established
connectedToGC
Got handled GC message MatchmakingGC2ClientHello
Got unhandled GC message 9194
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
Got handled GC message PlayersProfile
{ my_current_event_teams: [],
  my_current_event_stages: [],
  account_id: xxxxxxxx,
  ongoingmatch: null,
  global_stats: null,
  penalty_seconds: null,
  penalty_reason: null,
  vac_banned: null,
  ranking:
   { account_id: xxxxxxxx,
     rank_id: 16,
     wins: 1073,
     rank_change: null },
  commendation: { cmd_friendly: 57, cmd_teaching: 50, cmd_leader: 50 },
  medals:
   { display_items_defidx:
      [ 1331, 4551, 1376, 970, 1367, 4356, 1358, 1337, 1341, 1329 ],
     medal_team: null,
     medal_combat: null,
     medal_weapon: null,
     medal_global: null,
     medal_arms: null,
     featured_display_item_defidx: 1331 },
  my_current_event: null,
  my_current_team: null,
  survey_vote: null,
  activity: null,
  player_level: 24,
  player_cur_xp: 327680185,
  player_xp_bonus_flags: null }
before
after
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
Sending GC message ClientRequestPlayersProfile
Got handled GC message PlayersProfile
{ my_current_event_teams: [],
  my_current_event_stages: [],
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems here -

- Callback style functions in `forEach` which doesn't work the way you are expecting it to work. Either use `Promise.all` or `for..of`
- `mssql` supports promise so no need to use callback style to make things complicated and hard to read.
- Convert the callback style to promise.

I have modified the code. It will look something like this

```
function getRequestPlayer(account_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    csgo.requestPlayersProfile(account_id, function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

csgo.on("connectedToGC", async function () {
  console.log("connectedToGC");
  // Check connection to game coordinator
  if (csgo.haveGCSession) {

    // Check Database
    const connection = await pool.getConnection();
    const rows = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (MainSteamGroup = '1' || CommunitySteamGroup = '1' || vip = '1') && BotInFriendlist = '1'");
    await Promise.all(rows.map(row => {
      const account_id = new SteamID(`${row.SteamID64}`);
      return getRequestPlayer(account_id);
    }));
  }
});
```

You might need to tweak few things here and there but you will get an idea. Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried it, but it's not working with a setInterval.
Without the setInterval I get this error: https://pastebin.com/raw/wVtbeah6